# Which partial derivative notation for $\partial_j f_{,i}$ is correct: $f_{,ji}$ or $f_{,ij}$?

Tags: notation

I have a notation question: Which partial derivative notation for $\partial_j f_{,i}$ is correct: $f_{,ji}$ or $f_{,ij}$?

I think $f_{,ji}$ is correct.

Best regards

Comment: Why would you mix notations like that in the first place? It's a matter of if you read it as $(\partial_j f)_{,i}$, or  $\partial_j(f_{,i})$.

Comment: It is an equivalence relation on notation space. Does it make sense? It may be useful on Einstein's notation usage

Comment: Like I said, you're just inviting trouble for yourself. This notation is bad precisely because it can be interpreted two ways if you do not put in parentheses.

Comment: It is not an invitation if my surname is "trouble".

Comment: In my opinion, these you propose are different situation, which have different notations: $(f_{j})_i$ is not in Einstein's notation, the correct form is $f_{,j}^i$.

Comment: Even for Einstein notation, it's better to stick to one. Personally, I find commas clearer because of products. By this I mean $\partial_i fg$ vs $f_i g$. Is there a specific instance where you have a strong case for the mixed notation?

Comment: Stack-bot asked for us to take a room for discussion. Will you join?

Comment: No, I'm busy right now. I'll end with this: $f^i_,j$ is not the same as $f_{,ij}$! The first denotes taking the $j$th derivative of the function $f$ after projected onto the $i$th component. The second denotes taking the $i$ then $j$ partial derivative of the function $f$.

Comment: Ok. Your latter explanation clarifies the question as $\partial_j f_{,i} = \partial_j f_{,ij}$. I am inclined to believe this is not correct because it must be consistent to left-right order on operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j \, \partial x^i}$-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial_j f_{,i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)$

Therefore $f_{,ij}$

Comment: May you read OP last comment?